# osTicket emails show as sent from wrong address

Tags: linux, email, email-server

I'm currently trying to configure osTicket to act as our support system.  Everything seems to be working pretty much as expected.  However when an email sent by the system is received, instead of showing as

from support@company.com

it shows as

from support@company.com  on behalf of Support Team

As you can imagine this is not ideal and needs to be fixed, but I can't see what the problem is.  We are using an email address hosted on the same server as the website, connecting via SMTP.  We are not using the PHP mail function.

Incoming email is working fine, new tickets are being created from emails.  I've set the email account to allow header spoofing, but can't see any options.

In the end we are hoping to have outgoing emails sent from email@company.com but show as support@company.com in the from field.  If anyone can help with that as I would be grateful.

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the answer.  osTicket had been set to use SMTP, but it had been set to do so without authentication.  When it was set to use authentication the email address was displayed correctly in outgoing mail.

Also it will show any email address that you put in the Email Address field at the top of the email settings which answers the second part of the question.

Thanks for looking.